# pass function argument to tidyr::spread

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to pass function argument to tidyr::spread (version tidyr_0.6), as illustrated in the example below. My function argument is a string (variable name).  I got error message. Does anyone know why? How can I modify my code to make it work?

```
# data
stocks <- data.frame(
    time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
    X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
    Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
    Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time)

#function
spread.data <- function (var){
    var = sym(var)
    stocksm %>% spread(stock, !!var)
}

spread.data('price')
```

I got error message.

```
Error: Invalid column specification
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Your code worked for me. I did specify `rlang::sym` though. Did you have any other loaded package with a similar function name?

Comment: @zesla worked for me as well ! 
Although I'm confused, what does '!!' (double negation) before var means ?

Comment: @AkarshJain, some examples using `!!` with dplyr can be found at http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#programming-recipes.

Comment: @ AkarshJain thanks a lot. very useful link!

Comment: @Z.Lin   Thanks. It was tidyr_0.6 that cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment by @Z.lin might be correct.  Here is a reproducible example which uses `rlang::sym` function.  Note an identical result can be achieved without using the `sym` function at all.  I used `tidyr_0.7.0` to get this result:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rlang))

# data
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time)

# with rlang::sym function
spread.data <- function (var){
  var = sym(var)
  stocksm %>% spread(stock, !!var)
}

result1 <- spread.data('price')

# without sym function
spread.data <- function (var){
  stocksm %>% spread(stock, !!var)
}

result2 <- spread.data('price')

identical(result1, result2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the info link. :) (Y)

Comment: @markdly    Thanks a lot. I found what the problem is. (Not type)   I'm using tidyr_0.6, which comes with tidyverse.   tidyr_0.7 works for me.